# What are all the Vimperator highlight keywords?

Tags: vimperator

I'm trying out several colorschemes for Vimperator.  None of them seem to have a complete set of highlight keywords.  And there are some that have a whole bunch that turn out be invalid.

Is there a way to dump all the highlight keywords that these guys know about?  Or is there an authoritative colorscheme file somewhere that I could adapt?

Answer (score 1):

Gah, ":help highlight" brings up a list. There are far fewer of these that in Pentadactyl, which was confusing me because I was bringing Pentadactyl colorschemes over to Vimperator.